# How to change the text view when a new user is logged in?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a android payroll application when a user is logged in it should show his / her details in the navigation screen. And when a new user is logged in it should automatically change the details how can I do that please help me.

I know I've asked this question before but when I put for example

1. Login.xml

   ```
     <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
           android:src="@drawable/civilsoft" />

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutName"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
           app:errorEnabled="true">

           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/editTextName"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="User Name"
               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               />
       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
           app:errorEnabled="true"
           app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
           app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
               android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="Password"
               android:inputType="textPassword"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               />
       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
           android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
           android:text="login"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textViewCreateAccount"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           />
   </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
   ```
2. Login Activity

   ```
      //Declaration EditTexts
   EditText editTextName;
   EditText editTextPassword;
   //Declaration TextInputLayout
   TextInputLayout textInputLayoutName;
   TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;
   //Declaration Button
   Button buttonLogin;
   //Declaration DatabaseHelper
   DatabaseHelper DH;

   private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
   DH = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   initCreateAccountTextView();
   initViews();
   //set click event of login button
   buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Check user input is correct or not
           if (validate()){
               // Get values from edit text fields.
               String Name = editTextName.getText().toString();
               String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

               // Authenticate User
               User currentUser = DH.Authenticate(new User(null, null, Name, Password));



               //Check Authentication is successful or not
               if (currentUser != null) {
                   //Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Login Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   //User Logged in successfully Launch You home screen activity

                   Intent intent = new Intent (Login.this,Navigation.class);

                   intent.putExtra("EmpID", Employee.getEmpID());
                   intent.putExtra("EmpCode", Employee.getEmpCode());
                   intent.putExtra("EmpName", Employee.getEmpName());

                   startActivity(intent);
                   finish();
               } else {
                   // User Logged in failed.
                   Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Login Failed, please try again!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       }
       // This method is used to validate input given by user
       private boolean validate() {
           boolean valid = false;

           // Get values from editText fields
           String Name = editTextName.getText().toString();
           String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

           // Handling validation for User Name field.
           if(Name.isEmpty()){
               valid = false;
               textInputLayoutName.setError("Please enter valid User Name!");
           } else {
               valid = true;
               textInputLayoutName.setError(null);
           }
           // Handling validation for Password field.
           if(Password.isEmpty()) {
               valid = false;
               textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Please enter valid Password!");
           } else {
               textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
           }
           return valid;
       }
   });
   }


         // This method is used to connect XML views to its objects
          private void initViews() {
          editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
           editTextPassword = (EditText) 
          findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
          textInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) 
         findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutName);
          textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) 
         findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
         TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmpID);
          TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmpCode);
          TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmpName);


       buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
      }
      // This method is for handling fromHTML method depreciation.
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
        Spanned result;
         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
       android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
       } else {
           result = Html.fromHtml(html);
       }
       return result;
   }

      // This method used to set Create account TextView text and click event 
    (multiple colors
       // for TextView yet not supported in XML so I have done it 
       programmatically)
       private void initCreateAccountTextView() {
         TextView textViewCreateAccount = (TextView) 
       findViewById(R.id.textViewCreateAccount);
       textViewCreateAccount.setText(fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>I don't 
    have account yet. </font><font color='#0c0099'>create one</font>"));
            textViewCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new 
      View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
   }
   }
   ```
3. Content_Navigation.xml

   ```
     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linear"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/EmpID"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@string/EmpId"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
       android:textSize="25dp" />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/EmpCode"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:text="@string/EmpCode"
       android:textSize="25dp"
       android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
       />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/EmpName"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:text="@string/EmpCode"
       android:textSize="25dp"
       android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
       />



     </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. Navigation Activity

   ```
      //Declaration Textview;
      TextView EmpID, EmpCode, EmpName;
        // EmployeeHelper db;
        EmployeeHelper mydb;



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

   mydb = new EmployeeHelper(this);
    mydb.insertData("112", "002", "xxx");
     mydb.getAllData();

      TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmpID);
      TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmpCode);
      TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmpName);

      String EmpID = getIntent().getStringExtra("EmpID");
      String EmpCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("EmpCode");
      String EmpName = getIntent().getStringExtra("EmpName");

          textView.setText("EmpID - 112");
          textView1.setText("EmpCode - 002");
          textView2.setText("EmpName - xxx");
          textView.setText("EmpID - 111");
          textView1.setText("EmpCode - 001");
          textView2.setText("EmpName - bbb");

         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
      findViewById(R.id.fab);
      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
           Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
           Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                   .setAction("Action", null).show();
           }
          });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
       findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
           this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
         R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
          drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
         toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
        findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
       navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
       }


      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
      findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
       drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       } else {
       super.onBackPressed();
        }
        }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
      present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
     return true;
       }

     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
      int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
       }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

     @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
         int id = item.getItemId();

         if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
       // Handle the intent code to navigate from one page to another.
       startActivity( new Intent(Navigation.this, LeaveTran.class));
         } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
       startActivity( new Intent(Navigation.this, 
         PersonalProfile.class));
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
       // Handle the intent code to navigate from one page to another.
       startActivity( new Intent(Navigation.this, Home.class));
        }

   DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
   return true;
        }
        }
   ```
5. Database Helper

   ```
     public class EmployeeHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
      public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_database.db2";
      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Employee";
     public static final String KEY_EmpID = "EmpID";
     public static final String KEY_EmpCode = "EmpCode";
     public static final String KEY_EmpName = "EmpName";
      //SQL for creating users table
     public static final String SQL_TABLE_NAME = " CREATE TABLE " + 
       TABLE_NAME
       + " ( "
       + KEY_EmpID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
       + KEY_EmpCode + " TEXT, "
       + KEY_EmpName + " TEXT"
       + " ) ";

    public EmployeeHelper(Context context) {

         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

      @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(SQL_TABLE_NAME);
      }

    @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
      newVersion) {
       db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        }

      public boolean insertData(String EmpID, String EmpCode, String 
          EmpName) 
         {
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
           ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
           contentValues.put(KEY_EmpID, EmpID);
           contentValues.put(KEY_EmpCode, EmpCode);
           contentValues.put(KEY_EmpName, EmpName);
           long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues); // 
            error here
        // If data is inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
          return false;
        } else {
       return true;
        }
      }

      public List<String> getAllCategory() {
       List<String> AllCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

       /*db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, 
       Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       Cursor allrows = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Categ_NAME, 
             null);
         System.out.println("COUNT : " + allrows.getCount());*/

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {

           String EmpID = cursor.getString(0);
           String EmpCode = cursor.getString(1);
           String EmpName = cursor.getString(2);
           AllCategoryList.add(EmpID);
           AllCategoryList.add(EmpCode);
           AllCategoryList.add(EmpName);

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   cursor.close();
   db.close();
   return AllCategoryList;
     }


         public Cursor getAllData() {


          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

   String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

   Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

   return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }


       }
   ```
6. Employee Class

   ```
         public class Employee {
        public static String EmpID;
        public static String EmpCode;
        public static String EmpName;

          public Employee (String EmpID, String EmpCode, String EmpName) 
        {
               this.EmpID  = EmpID;
               this.EmpCode  = EmpCode;
              this.EmpName  = EmpName;
              }

   public static String getEmpID() {
   return EmpID;
   }

   public static String getEmpCode() {
   return EmpCode;
    }

    public static String getEmpName() {
   return EmpName;
    }

    public static void setEmpID(String empID) {
   EmpID = empID;
    }

    public static void setEmpCode(String empCode) {
   EmpCode = empCode;
    }

       public static void setEmpName(String empName) {
      EmpName = empName;
        }
   ```

   This is how it is showing:

   [image]

Comment: get the user details in response of your login and after that store all the information which you want to display on next screen

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: use shared preferences rather than SQLite for saving small data

Comment: I don't how to use shared preferences properly sir.

Comment: ok I will post my code to show to save a retrieve a shared preferences

Comment: But will this help me in automatically display the details when the new user is logged in and shown

Comment: try this code I am also using this code for saving and retrieve data of user login and new user register time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one Global PrefManager class like this and create a three field to set data

```
public class PrefManager {
    // Shared preferences file name
    public static final String PREF_NAME = "PACKAGE_NAME" + "_Preferences";




private static final String KEY_EMPID = "Emp_ID";
    private static final String KEY_EMPCODE = "Emp_Code";
    private static final String KEY_EMP_NAME = "Emp_Name";

  SharedPreferences pref;
    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;
    // Context
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }



public String getEmpID() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_EMPID, null);
    }

    public void setEmpID(String token) {
        editor.putString(KEY_EMPID, token);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getEmpCode() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_EMPCODE, null);
    }

    public void setEmpCode(String token) {
        editor.putString(KEY_EMPCODE, token);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_EMP_NAME, null);
    }

    public void setEmpName(String token) {
        editor.putString(KEY_EMP_NAME, token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Login Activity Call Intent Time Set Data to shared Preferences you also save data on the register time

```
public class LoginActivity{

PrefManager pref;


  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
// inilize pref manager class
 pref = new PrefManager(this);

}

 if (currentUser != null) {
                //Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Login Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //User Logged in successfully Launch You home screen activity

                Intent intent = new Intent (Login.this,Navigation.class);


pref.setEmpID(//passyour employee id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

on navigation, activity get data from shared preferences and store to string and set to drawer textview

```
  public class navigationActivity()

***PrefManager pref;***
String EmpId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    ***pref = new PrefManager(this);***
    EmpId = pref.getEmpID;
    }

    // OnnavigationDrawer header

     textView.setText("EmpID:"+EmpId);
```

Comment: Sir I'm getting errors in this EmpId = pref.getEmpID; in the navigation Activity saying that "Cannot resolve symbol getEmpID" and in PrefManager Class also I'm getting error like public String getEmpID() {
        return pref.getStringKEY_EMPID, null);
    }
cannot resovle symbol "getStringKEY_EMPID" what should I do?

Comment: when you save id to shared preferences?

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: Now in the login Activity I can add the pref.setEmpID(//passyour employee id) same EmpCode and EmpName right

Comment: yes you can save all three things in shared preferences and get data into navigation activity pref.getEmpID; like this

Comment: In the Navigation Activity when I write these I'm getting this error called 
EmpId = pref.getEmpID; "Cannot resolve symbol to getEmpID"
        EmpCode = pref.getEmpCode; "Cannot resolve symbol to getEmpCode"
        EmpName = pref.getEmpName; "Cannot resolve symbol to getEmpName"

Comment: Declare this line globally on activity
PrefManager pref;
and initialize prefmanager oncreate()
pref = new PrefManager(this);

Comment: I have to declare it in PrefManager class right but where do i have to put it.

Comment: hey, i think you have wrong declared a Prefmanager. just show my answer in navigation activity.

Comment: PrefManager pref;
    String EmpId;
    String   EmpCode ;

EmpId = pref.getEmpID;
        EmpCode = pref.getEmpCode;
        EmpName = pref.getEmpName; <----- here I'm getting errors

Comment: Initilize pref manager like this in oncrete() pref = new PrefManager(this);

Comment: Sir I executed the code but I'm getting null values @Mayur Panchal

Comment: okay which value set in this... pref.setEmpID(//passyour employee id);

Comment: See I did like this :

 if (currentUser != null) {
                        //Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Login Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //User Logged in successfully Launch You home screen activity

                        Intent intent = new Intent (Login.this,Navigation.class);

                        pref.setEmpID("EmpID" );
                                 pref.setEmpCode("EmpCode");
                                         pref.setEmpName("EmpName");
                                                 startActivity(intent);

Comment: EmpID?? which value you put

Comment: In my database I've put EmpID = "111"

Comment: so you can directly put  pref.setEmpID("111"); or fetch a userid from databse table and set to pref

Comment: have you checked share preferences value into Device File Explorer?

Comment: Yes I've checked the data is showing but its not displaying on the navigation menu screen when I login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192717/discussion-between-mayur-panchal-and-huzaifa-yusuf).